# Как узнать время выполнения кода в тактах

Tags: stm32, arm

Есть кусок кода, как измерить за сколько тактов он будет выполнен?
В `AVRах` помню в студии просто можно было увидеть текущий такт выполнения и время (задав частоту), как быть с `STM32`?

Answer (score 3):

То же самое, но без 'magic numbers', используя определения из CMSIS

```
CoreDebug->DEMCR |= CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk; // Разрешаем TRACE
DWT->CTRL |= DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk; // Разрешаем счетчик тактов
DWT->CYCCNT = 0; // Обнуляем счетчик
// Здесь идет измеряемый код
cycles_count = DWT->CYCCNT; // Читаем счетчик тактов
```

Answer (score 2):

В нем есть спец счетчик, вот так можно использовать:

```
#define    DWT_CYCCNT    *(volatile unsigned long *)0xE0001004
#define    DWT_CONTROL   *(volatile unsigned long *)0xE0001000
#define    SCB_DEMCR     *(volatile unsigned long *)0xE000EDFC
  SCB_DEMCR |= 0x01000000;
  DWT_CONTROL|= 1; // enable the counter
  DWT_CYCCNT  = 0;
  for(i=0;i<1000;i++){};
  time=DWT_CYCCNT;
```

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0439c/BABJFFGJ.html - тут подробнее про эти регистры

Answer (score 1):

Вставлю свои 3 копейки.

```
 volatile uint32_t *DWT_CONTROL = (uint32_t *)0xE0001000;
volatile uint32_t *DWT_CYCCNT = (uint32_t *)0xE0001004; 
volatile uint32_t *DEMCR = (uint32_t *)0xE000EDFC; 
uint32_t Mcounter, count;
```

Это вставляем в начало main()

```
 // enable the use DWT
*DEMCR = *DEMCR | 0x01000000;

// Reset cycle counter
*DWT_CYCCNT = 0; 

// enable cycle counter
*DWT_CONTROL = *DWT_CONTROL | 1 ;
//-------------------------------------------------------
```

Это ставим в начале блока, который хотим посчитать

```
Mcounter=*DWT_CYCCNT;
```

А это в конце того самого блока.

```
count=*DWT_CYCCNT-Mcounter;
float op_time=count/72000000.0f;// count/F_CPU
```

Итого в переменной count - тики проца, в op_time - время выполнения в сек.